# Получить ссылку на другой документ из эксель

Tags: python, openpyxl

Есть файл .xlsx в нем есть ссылка на файл с того же пк нужно получить результат примерно следующего содержания:

```
 ='C:\Users\USER\Desktop\ексель_список\[2.xlsx]Лист1'!$A$1
```

- данная формула в ячейке А1

Вместо этого я получаю: `=[1]Лист1!$A$1`

использую следующий код:

```
import openpyxl

path = r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\ексель_список\1.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheets = wb.sheetnames
for sheet in sheets:
            print(sheet)

sheet = wb['Лист1']
print(sheet['a1'].value)
```

В итоге все сводится к тому, что вместо ожидаемого `'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\ексель_список\[2.xlsx]` получаю усечение в виде [1] Спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 1):

Да `openpyxl` не достает полную формулу при ссылке, но медленно и верно работает `xlwings`:

```
import xlwings as xw


book = xw.books.open(r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\ексель_список\1.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheets['Лист1']
print(sheet['a1'].formula)
```

Comment: спасибо, но нет hyperlink и link для openpyxl не равны
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'target'

Comment: @МаксимЦарьков Изменил ответ.